# use selected data to search mysql table and set value of input field

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-chosen

I am having difficulty using the change event in jquery-chosen, to search a mysql table and use the column found as the default in an input field in a form. I initially store registration numbers as options in a select drop-down. Here is the code:

```
    //store reg_1 options
 $get_1=mysql_query("SELECT reg, reg_date FROM vehicle_reg");
$option_reg = '<option value = ""></option>';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_1))
{

  $option_reg .= '<option value = "'.$row['reg'].'">'.$row['reg'].'</option>';
}
```

the html form uses jquery-chosen:

```
        <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="reg_1" name="reg_1"  data-placeholder="Choose a reg..." style="width:135px;" class="chosen-select" required ><?php echo $option_reg; ?></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="reg_date_1" id="reg_date_1" value="<?php echo $reg_date; ?>"  readonly >
        </td>
```

and the on-change and search javascript:

```
          $(document).on('change', '#reg_1', function () {
        if ($("#reg_1 option:selected").val() !== "") {
            var reg = $("#reg_1 option:selected").val();
            search(reg);
            alert("well done!");
        } else {
            alert("select non-blank registration!");

        }
      });           

    function search(string){
        var xmlhttp;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "search_vehicle_reg.php?s="+string, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                var regDate = '@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["reg_date"]';
                document.getElementById("reg_date_1").value = $regDate;
            });
```

the php code for the mysql search:

```
<?php

include_once('connection.php');

if(isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s'] != ''){
    $s = $_GET['s'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `vehicle_reg` WHERE reg LIKE '%$s%'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $reg = $row['reg'];
        $reg_date = $row['reg_date'];
        $_SESSION['reg_date'] = $reg_date;
    }

} ?>
```

I can debug and see that the last line of the above php setting the session field 'reg_date' is correct, but the lines of javascript

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                var regDate = '@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["reg_date"]';
                document.getElementById("reg_date_1").value = $regDate;
            });
```

picking this up and putting it in the reg_date_1 input field don't seem to happen, and I am wondering if anyone can spot the problem.